# Logo and text wont go to top center in angular 2 home component

Tags: html, angular, sass

I am using an angular 2 front end for my app with a home component and a toolbar component(materialize navbar):

home.component.html:

```
  <figure id="container" class="white-text top center">
      <img id="logo" src="/assets/imagesLogoClearBGWhite.png" alt="">
      <figcaption id="phrase">
        Words<br> more words.
      </figcaption>
  </figure>
```

home.component.sass:

```
#logo
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.2)
     -moz-transform: scale(0.2)
      -ms-transform: scale(0.2)
       -o-transform: scale(0.2)
          transform: scale(0.2)
             filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.9999619230641713, M12=-0.008726535498373935, M21=0.008726535498373935, M22=0.9999619230641713,SizingMethod='auto expand');
```

toolbar.component.html:

```
<nav class="transparent">
   <div class="nav-wrapper">
     <a ref="#!" [routerLink]="['']" id="logo-container" class="brand-logo"></a>
     <a href="#" materialize="sideNav" data-activates="mobile-navBar" class="button-collapse white-text"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

      <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li *ngIf="!(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)"> <a (click)="presentAuthDialog()" >LOGIN</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="!(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)"> <a (click)="presentAuthDialog('register')">REGISTER</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)"><a [routerLink]="['/profile']">PROFILE</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)"><a (click)="logOut()">LOGOUT</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="dropdown-content" id="mobile-navBar">
        <li *ngIf="!(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)"> <a (click)="presentAuthDialog()" >LOGIN</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="!(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)"> <a (click)="presentAuthDialog('register')">REGISTER</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)"><a [routerLink]="['/profile']">PROFILE</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)"><a (click)="logOut()">LOGOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<app-auth-dialog #authDialog ></app-auth-dialog>
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>

<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BarrelFrontend</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
  <body style="background-image:url('/assets/images/cellarBackgroundImage.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center center;">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently my home screen looks like this [image]

but i had to zoom out a long way to get this picture and the logo should be at the top of the page with the text almost directly underneath. My background image is large but i dont understand why its not matching the size of the screen given?

Comment: create a plunker to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS properties need the final `;` in each line to be be well interpretated. As you can see in your screenshot, all the properties are prefixed with the first `--webkit` prefix...

Comment: when i add them i get errors, is this because its a sass file?

Comment: My bad, you are right, it's because you are using sass instead of scss. Maybe the indented prefix are misinterpretated. Do you still get the error if you align your properties on the same line on the left ? (without the `;`then)

Comment: so, if align all the properties to the left the ui doesnt change, it also doesnt complain if i add the ; at the end of each line though

Comment: It seems that the issue comes from the `filter` property. Not sure if you really need it (see [http://shouldiprefix.com/#transforms](http://shouldiprefix.com/#transforms)). Without the filter, and with your prefixes consistently indented, I managed to get a proper CSS with [https://www.sassmeister.com/](https://www.sassmeister.com/). Can you try it ?

Comment: so when i remove the filter nothing really changes, the transform seems to be the issue but i dont understand enough to scale the image another way

Comment: Can you send a picture of your input code, of the output css and of the error message please ?